# Using OAuth for Twitter

Tags: ios, twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

According to this [link](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview) , twitter provides 7 ways to access data using the twitter's REST api. I want to use develop an iOS application like twitter itself. I want to ask the user for its username and password and after login he can view his timeline and also post his tweets. According to what I have understood I should be using 3-legged authentication. However it is stated [here](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/3-legged) that "The user will always be prompted to authorize access to your application, even if access was previously granted." Can anyone guide me on which method to use to access twitter api using authorization from the user. I only want the user to enter the username and password only once.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]permanentlySetConsumerKey:kOAuthConsumerKey andSecret:kOAuthConsumerSecret];
[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]setDelegate:self]; 
[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loadAccessToken];
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to make the http requests and impement the sign in functionality by myself.